# Pandas DataFrame: Remove row satisfying certain condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame called `df`, containing a column called `_text`.  I want to remove all rows where the value in `_text` is not a string.

Initially I was doing this:

```
df['_text'] = df['_text'].apply(lambda t: t if isinstance(t, basestring) else '')
```

But that just sets it to the empty string.

How would I delete any row where the value in the `_text` column is not a string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, only need return boolean mask from `apply` and then use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) what return all `string`s values (so remove all not `string`s like numeric):

```
df[df['_text'].apply(lambda t: isinstance(t, basestring))]
```

Or:

```
df[df['_text'].apply(type) == basestring]
```

Sample:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'_text':[1,4,'ss','']})
print (df)
  _text
0     1
1     4
2    ss
3     

print (df['_text'].apply(lambda t: isinstance(t, basestring)))
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
Name: _text, dtype: bool

#for python 3 it return str,  for python 2 basestring
print (df['_text'].apply(type))
0    <class 'int'>
1    <class 'int'>
2    <class 'str'>
3    <class 'str'>
Name: _text, dtype: object

df1 = df[df['_text'].apply(lambda t: isinstance(t, basestring))]
print (df1)
  _text
2    ss
3      

df1 = df[df['_text'].apply(type) == basestring]
print (df1)
  _text
2    ss
3
```

Comment: Wouldn't that give me a boolean in the `_text` column instead of removing the row if it's not a string?

Comment: Hmm so `df['_text'] = df['_text'].apply(lambda t: t if isinstance(t, basestring) else '')` converts 380 of my entries to `''` but doing `df[df['_text'].apply(lambda t: isinstance(t, basestring))]` doesn't seem to remove any rows :(

Comment: What return `print (df['_text'].apply(lambda t: isinstance(t, basestring)))` ? True and False values ?

Comment: If return all `True`s it means all values are strings.

Comment: @jezrael It starts off with all `True` but, if it were all strings, I wouldn't get: `len(df[df['_text'] == ''])` to return 380 (which it does)

Comment: I am not sure if understand. If check `print (df['_text'].apply(type))` it return all strings or some strings and some numerics? because is possible some numeric can be converted to strings.

Comment: @jezrael So I load my dataframe.  I then run `len(df[df['_text'] == ''])` and get back 0.  Then I run `df['_text'] = df['_text'].apply(lambda t: t if isinstance(t, basestring) else '')`.  Finally I run `len(df[df['_text'] == ''])` and get back 380...So it must be that I had some non-strings in there to begin with (unfortunately it looks like your method doesn't remove the offending rows...)?

Comment: Hmmm, I think there is wrong `df['_text'] = df['_text'].apply(lambda t: t if isinstance(t, str) else '')` - if use it with my dataframe sample it remove all non numeric and replace values to empty strings. So in final dataframe are all values strings and mask return all Trues, so nothing is removed. try remove `df['_text'] = df['_text'].apply(lambda t: t if isinstance(t, str) else '')` and it should works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149807/discussion-between-bclayman-and-jezrael).